# How to get ImageURL path from firebase database using Swift3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'am trying to make profile picture for the user and I'am getting the ImageURL to database , Now I'am trying to display this ImageURL using SDWebImage , How can I get this ImageURL (filePath) from database to my Project.

this is my code.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Ref=FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    Ref?.child("Posts/\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)")
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with : { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.hasChild("userPhoto"){ 
            let filepath = // How to get the current ImageURL path
            let url = URL(string : filepath)
            self.profileImage.sd_setImage(with: url)
        }

        if let val = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
           self.passwordLable.text = val["Provider"] as? String
           self.emailLable.text = val["Email"] as? String
        }   
    })
}
```

Comment: A specific answer will depend on your Firebase structure. If you can post that as TEXT please, no images (Firebase console->Three dots on right->Export JSON) we can give you an answer. In general, you would have stored the path to the image in your firebase database, so you would read that child node for the path.

Comment: Yes , I stored the URL of image from storage to database , so how can I display this image as profile image for the current user using SDWebImage.

Comment: just depends on your data structure, show the node in which your image is saved